# Ayuda con programa en c++?

Tags: c++

Es un problema con los apuntadores.
Aquí tengo un programa que da de "alta" jugadores de fútbol, te pregunta el nombre del DT, y después te pide que llenes unos campos acerca de la información de tus jugadores.

El problema, es que el programa deja de funcionar cuando seleccionas que quieres dar de alta a 3 jugadores, es decir, te deja llenar todos los campos, pero al momento de la impresión de los datos el programa crashea.

Lo comprobé quitándole apuntadores, y funcionó. Y sinceramente no logro entender el problema.

Éste es mi código:

```
using namespace std;

#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

class Persona
 {
      private:
            string NomComp;
            int Edad;


     public:
        Persona( string NC = " " , int E = 1 );

        void Leer( void );
        void Imprimir( void );

 };



Persona::Persona( string NC , int E ) : NomComp ( NC ) , Edad ( E )
 {

 }

void Persona::Leer( void )
 {

    cout<< "\t\tDame el Nombre Completo: " ;
    getline( cin, NomComp);
    cout<< "\t\tDame la Edad: ";
    cin>> Edad;

    cout<< endl;
    fflush ( stdin );

 }

void Persona::Imprimir( void )
 {
    cout<< "\t\tNombre Completo :" << NomComp << endl;

    cout<< "\t\tEdad : " << Edad << endl;       
 }


class Jugador : public Persona
 {
    private:
        string Posicion;
        string Apodo;
        string Equipo;


    public:
        Jugador ( string NC = " " , int E = 1 , string P = " " , 
                  string A = " " , string Eq = " " );

        void Leer( void );
        void Imprimir( void ) ;

 };



Jugador::Jugador ( string NC  , int E  , string P , string A  , string Eq  ) 
                  : Persona ( NC , E), Posicion ( P ) , Apodo ( A ) , 
                   Equipo ( Eq )
 {

 }      



void Jugador::Leer( void )
 {
    static int n = 1;

    cout << "\t\tJugador : " << n << endl;
    Persona::Leer();
    cout << "\t\tPosicion : ";
    getline(cin, Posicion);
    cout << "\t\tApodo : ";
    getline(cin, Apodo);
    cout << "\t\tEquipo : ";
    getline(cin, Equipo);

    cout << endl;

    n++;

 }
void Jugador::Imprimir( void ) 

 {
    static int n = 1;

    cout << "Jugador " << n << endl;
    Persona::Imprimir( );
    cout << "\t\tPosicion : " << Posicion << endl
         << "\t\tApodo    : " << Apodo << endl
         << "\t\tEquipo   : " << Equipo
         << endl << endl;

    n++;

 }


class Seleccion : public Jugador

 {
    private:
        string Pais;


        Persona* ApDT;

        int NumJug;
        Jugador* ArreJug;

    public:
        Seleccion ( int NJ = 2 , string Pa = " ");
        Seleccion( Seleccion& Sel);


        void Leer( void );
        void Imprimir( void );

        Seleccion& operator = ( Seleccion& Sel2 );

        ~Seleccion( void );

 };

Seleccion::Seleccion ( int NJ, string Pa ) : NumJug ( NJ ), Pais ( Pa ) 

 {
      ApDT = new Persona;

      ArreJug = new Jugador[ NumJug ];
 }


Seleccion::Seleccion( Seleccion& Sel)
    {
        Pais = Sel.Pais;

        ApDT = new Persona;
        *ApDT = *( Sel.ApDT );

        NumJug = Sel.NumJug;
        ArreJug = new Jugador[ NumJug ];

        for ( int i = 0; i < NumJug; i++)
            ArreJug [ i ] = Sel.ArreJug [ i ];  
    }

void Seleccion:: Leer( void )
    {

    fflush ( stdin );
    cout << "Dame El Pais: ";
    getline (cin,Pais);
    cout << "Nombre del Director Tecnico" << endl;
    ApDT-> Leer ();
    for (int i = 0;i < NumJug; i++)
      {
        ArreJug[i].Leer (); 
      }
    cout << endl;

    }

void Seleccion:: Imprimir( void )

    {

    cout << "Pais: " << Pais << endl;
    cout << "Nombre del Director Tecnico: "
         << endl;
    ApDT->Imprimir();

    cout << "Jugadores " << endl;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < NumJug ; i++)
        {
          ArreJug[i].Imprimir();    
        }

    }

Seleccion& Seleccion::operator = ( Seleccion& Sel2 )
    {
        if ( this != &Sel2 )
            {
                if ( NumJug != Sel2.NumJug )
                    {
                            delete[] ArreJug;
                            ArreJug = new Seleccion [Sel2.NumJug];
                    }

                Pais = Sel2.Pais;
                *ApDT = *( Sel2.ApDT);
                NumJug = Sel2.NumJug;

                for ( int i = 0; i < NumJug; i++)
                    ArreJug [ i ] = Sel2.ArreJug [ i ];
            }
        return *this;

    }

Seleccion::~Seleccion( void )
 {
    delete ApDT;
    delete[] ArreJug;   

 }


int NumeroJug ( void );

int NumeroJug ( void )

 {
    int NJ;
    cout << "Dame el numero de Jugadores: ";
    cin >> NJ;
    cout << endl;

    return NJ;  
 }

int main ( void )
 {

    system( "cls");

    int NJ;
    NJ = NumeroJug();

    Seleccion* AptP;
    AptP = new Seleccion ( NJ );

    AptP->Leer( );


    Seleccion* AptP2 = new Seleccion;
    Seleccion* AptP3 = new Seleccion;

    *AptP3 = *AptP2 = *AptP;

    cout << "ORIGINAL" << endl;
    AptP -> Imprimir( );
    cout << "ASIGNADO" << endl;
    AptP2 -> Imprimir ( );
    cout << "ASIGNADO" << endl;
    AptP3 -> Imprimir ( );

    delete AptP2;
    delete AptP3;
    delete AptP;

    system( "pause ");


    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: El título ¿Es una pregunta o una afirmación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Seleccion::Seleccion( Seleccion& Sel)
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < NumJug; i++)
    ArreJug [ i ] = Sel.ArreJug [ i ]; // <<---
}

Seleccion& Seleccion::operator = ( Seleccion& Sel2 )
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < NumJug; i++)
    ArreJug [ i ] = Sel2.ArreJug [ i ]; // <<---
}
```

Las líneas destacada con el comentario hace una copia de objetos... ¿Seguro que con polimorfismo quieres hacer eso?

```
struct A
{
  virtual void test()
  { std::cout << "A"; }
}

struct B : A
{
  void test()
  { std::cout << "B"; }
}

int main()
{
  B *b = new B();

  b->test(); // Imprime B

  A a = *b;
  a.test(); // Imprime A

  delete b;
}
```

Al hacer una copia de un objeto se pierden todo el polimorfismo que puedas haber creado. Para solventar este problema en casos de polimorfismo se suele recurrir a la lista de punteros (en tu caso `ArreJug` debería ser un puntero doble) y a la clonación:

```
struct A
{
  virtual void test()
  { std::cout << "A"; }

  virtual A* clone()
  { return new A(this); }
}

struct B : A
{
  void test()
  { std::cout << "B"; }

  void clone()
  { return new B(this); }
}

int main()
{
  B *b = new B();

  b->test(); // Imprime B

  A* a = b->clone();
  a->test(); // Imprime B

  delete b;
  delete a;
}
```

Lo que sucede es que no te llegas a encontrar este error porque antes se está produciendo uno complicado de encontrar:

```
Seleccion& Seleccion::operator = ( Seleccion& Sel2 )
{
  delete[] ArreJug;
  ArreJug = new Seleccion [Sel2.NumJug]; // <<---
}
```

Si `ArreJug` es de tipo `Jugador*`... ¿Por qué haces una reserva de tipo `Seleccion[]`? `Seleccion[]` va a crear una secuencia de objetos de tipo `Seleccion` ([ver ejemplo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dNxTjx5oZOGNxoyt)):

```
struct A
{
  A(){ std::cout << "A::A()\n"; }
};

struct B : A
{
  B(){ std::cout << "B::B()\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  A* lista = new B[3];

  // delete[] lista; // lo omito a propósito
}
```

Como puedes ver en este ejemplo, llamar a `new B[3]` crea 3 objetos de tipo `B`... pero el programa entiende que `lista` va a almacenar objetos de tipo `A`... si `A` y `B` no tienen el mismo tamaño esto provoca desalineamiento, lo que degenera en [comportamientos inesperados](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gWdTnadi92ShQBXC):

```
struct A
{
    A(int x) : x(x) { }

    int x;
};

struct B : A
{
    B() : A(1), y(2) { }

    int y;
};

int main()
{
  A* lista = new B[3];

  std::cout << lista[0].x << lista[1].x << lista[2].x;
}
```

Y claro, esto acaba afectando negativamente al ciclo de vida de los objetos... En el momento en el que tenemos polimorfismo se hace necesario que el compilador cree lo que se conocen como "*vtables*" o tablas virtuales. Estas tablas permiten ejecutar los métodos virtuales que se hayan sobreescrito en clases hijas... si los datos no están alineados el puntero donde debería encontrarse la `vtable` no es correcto y a partir de ahí el programa empieza a hacer cosas raras:

```
struct A
{ };

struct B : A // No hay metodos virtuales = no hay vtable
{ };

struct vA
{
  virtual ~vA(){ }
};

struct vB : vA // metodos virtuales = hay vtable
{ };

int main()
{
  std::cout << sizeof(B) << '\n'
            << sizeof(vB) << '\n';
}
```

[En mi caso](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VXiwABi4RYzNvBEn) el programa imprime lo siguiente:

```
1
8
```

En cuanto hay un método virtual vemos como el tamaño de la clase se incrementa para poder contener el correspondiente puntero a la tabla virtual. El byte que ocupa la clase sin métodos virtuales es meramente simbólico (la clase está vacía y 1 byte es la unidad mínima de información).

Así pues si cambias la construcción del array a:

```
if ( NumJug != Sel2.NumJug )
{
  delete[] ArreJug;
  ArreJug = new Jugador[Sel2.NumJug];
}
```

conseguirás que el programa, al menos en esa parte, funcione correctamente.